# Convert column layout into row layout

Tags: excel, excel-2010

How can I move the columns into rows but leave some of the data alone in the rows?

For example:
[image]

Comment: A combination of ROW () & OFFSET () will do this quite easily. Read about these functions

Answer (score 0):

Click on F2, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+D, P, select `Multiple consolidation ranges`, <kbd>Next ></kbd>, select `I will create the page fields`, <kbd>Next ></kbd>, in `Range:` enter: A2:D6, <kbd>Add</kbd>, <kbd>Next ></kbd>, <kbd>Finish</kbd>, double-click on J10, select Rows2:7 and drag down to Row14. Delete Rows2:7. Click on A1, right-click, Table, Convert to Range, <kbd>Yes</kbd>, enter "Product Name" and blank B1:C1. Format to suit.